# Disable chapter gaps in custom "listof" in KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{%
  toc=listof,
  listof=leveldown,
  listof=nochaptergap,
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\NN}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}

\begin{document}

\addtotoclist[algorithm2e]{loa}
\setuptoc{loa}{%
  chapteratlist, totoc, leveldown%
}
\newcommand*{\listofloaname}{\listalgorithmcfname}
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\listoftoc{loa}}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\mainmatter%
\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example Image A}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm for Computing \(n!\)}
  \DontPrintSemicolon{}
  \KwIn{\(n \in \NN\)}
  \KwOut{\(n!\)}
  \Begin{%
    \uIf{\(n = 0\)}{%
      \Return{\(1\)}%
    }
    \Else{%
      \Return{\(\prod_{k = 1}^{n} k\)}%
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Example Image B}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Another Algorithm for Computing \(n!\)}
  \DontPrintSemicolon{}
  \KwIn{\(n \in \NN\)}
  \KwOut{\(n!\)}
  \Begin{%
    \uIf{\(n = 0\)}{%
      \Return{\(1\)}%
    }
    \Else{%
      \Return{\(\prod_{k = 1}^{n} k\)}%
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\backmatter%
\end{document}
```

The table of contents produced is the following: [image: Table of Contents with gap between entries in List of Algorithms]

Namely, notice the chapter gap between the two entries under the *List of Algorithms*.  This gap is absent from the entries in the *List of Figures* because of the `listof=nochaptergap` option that was specified in the preamble; however, the *List of Algorithms* does not seem to honor that option.  Is there any way to fix that?  Perhaps some argument to `\setuptoc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `algorithm2e` redefines the chapter command to add the additional space to the List of Algorithms. To disable this changes use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand{chapter}
```

when package `algorithm2e` is loaded.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{%
  toc=listof,
  listof=leveldown,
  listof=nochaptergap,
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\RedeclareSectionCommand{chapter}% <- added

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\NN}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}

\addtotoclist[algorithm2e]{loa}
\setuptoc{loa}{%
  chapteratlist,totoc, leveldown%
}

\newcommand*{\listofloaname}{\listalgorithmcfname}
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\listoftoc{loa}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms
\mainmatter%
\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example Image A}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm for Computing \(n!\)}
  \DontPrintSemicolon{}
  \KwIn{\(n \in \NN\)}
  \KwOut{\(n!\)}
  \Begin{%
    \uIf{\(n = 0\)}{%
      \Return{\(1\)}%
    }
    \Else{%
      \Return{\(\prod_{k = 1}^{n} k\)}%
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Example Image B}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Another Algorithm for Computing \(n!\)}
  \DontPrintSemicolon{}
  \KwIn{\(n \in \NN\)}
  \KwOut{\(n!\)}
  \Begin{%
    \uIf{\(n = 0\)}{%
      \Return{\(1\)}%
    }
    \Else{%
      \Return{\(\prod_{k = 1}^{n} k\)}%
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}
\backmatter%
\end{document}
```